# determinant and invertibility for matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm reading this in my text:

[image]

I don't understand this at all: (see attachment)

It's the second part that I don't get. I get that if B has a row of 0s, then the determinant is 0 (I could cofactor expand this and it'd be 0). But here's what I don't get:

- if $|B| = 0$, why does this imply that $|A| = 0$? Where does this come from?
- if A is row equivalent to I, why does this mean that A is invertible?

Comment: Do you know what the "row-reduced echelon form" **is**?  Every step in "row reduction" is the same as multiplying the matrix by an "elementary matrix"- the matrix you get by applying that step to the identity matrix.

Comment: For "why does this mean that $A$ is invertible", the proof cites Theorem 2.15. I do not know what Theorem 2.15 is in your book, but you have the book and can look it up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to see it is that $B$ can be obtained from $A$ by applying elementary operations. So 
$$\tag1
B=E_1\cdots E_mA
$$
for certain elementary matrices $E_1,\ldots,E_m$. As elementary matrices are invertible, their determinants are nonzero (as shown in the first paragraph you posted). So 
$$
\det B=\det E_1\cdots \det E_m\det A.
$$
Thus $\det B=0$ if and only if $\det A=0$.

And if $B=I$, we get from $(1)$ that $E_1\cdots E_m$ is an inverse for $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Note that every elementary row operation is a multiplication of your matrix by an invertible matrix.

So if you can reduce your matrix to the identity matrix via elementary row operations that means you have multiplied your matrix by some invertible matrices to get $I$, therefore the  product of those matrices is the inverse of your matrix.

Thus your matrix in invertible.

Comment: woah that is a good explanation.

Comment: If every elementary matrix is invertible, why is product of invertible matrices also invertible?

Comment: Note that $(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1}$